# How to create pretty virtual URL instead of absolute URL?

Tags: php, hyperlink, pretty-urls

I want to use the slash `/` in a link like:

```
Example.com/article/news/
```

But `article` and `news` are not directories in the web root, it's just a virtual link.

How to create a link like that?

Comment: Is your question about "creating links with HTML" or about "How to create a URL using PHP?" or about "How to use URL paths to controllers and actions?" Please read SO's [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In case you're generating URL's, feel free to replace "http://" and "https://" with just "//", this decides protocol based on the client-server connection already there or else on server preferences.

Answer (score -5):

add the 'http://' infront of the site

Comment: please add more of an explanation as to why you think this is the answer

Comment: it should work, try it dont criticize unless it doesnt work :|